# What happened to Hanuman's son Makardhwaja after he became the king of Patala?

Tags: ramayana, hanuman

I need to know the detailed story of Makardhwaja the son of Hanuman.

I know that he was born from sweat of Hanuman. Hanuman and Makardhwaja both  met in Patala when Hanuman was searching for Rama and Lakshmana in Patala.

And after that Rama advised  Hanuman to announce him as the king of patala.

I need to know what happened with Makardhvaja after he became the king of Patala.

If there is any reference then please share it.

Comment: The main question is what is the reference of Makara Dhwaja being son of Hanuman. If that is found, this will be easily known.

Comment: @Sinister, Thanks for your comment. I have read about makardhwaj [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Makardhwaja)

Comment: Makardhwaja had a son Modhdhwaja and grandson was Jethidhwaja. The Jethwa kshatriya clan of Saurashtra in Gujarat claim descent from him [Ref: 'Kutch Gurjar Kshatriya Community' by Raja Pawan Jethwa, Page 81].